# How to upgrade theme from 6.0.5 to Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay-7

As we upgrade database from Liferay 6.0.5 to 7.It time to upgrade themes from Liferay 6.0.5 to 7 but, I didn't any answer when I did small search in google. What are the steps that I need to follow for upgrade? Any suggestions?

Comment: My experience is: you can't "upgrade" themes from one major version to another - even more so if the jump covers three major versions. You need to create the 7.0 theme from scratch: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/themes-and-layout-templates

Answer (score 1):

there's a task defined in liferay 7 theme generator for it [upgrade]

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/upgrading-themes

Further there's a task for bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 3 migration.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-bootstrap-2-to-3

you can check gulp code in 
any liferay 7 theme's node module's  liferay-theme-tasks/lib/upgrade/6.2/upgrade.js

```
runSequence(
        'upgrade:black-list',
        'upgrade:replace-compass',
        'upgrade:convert-bootstrap',
        'upgrade:config',
        'upgrade:rename-core-files',
        'upgrade:create-css-diff',
        'upgrade:dependencies',
        'upgrade:create-deprecated-mixins',
        'upgrade:ftl-templates',
        'upgrade:vm-templates',
        'upgrade:log-changes',
        cb
    );
```

this involves all the steps needed.

Comment: The Liferay documentation says: "*A Liferay Portal 6.2 theme can be upgraded*" - does that mean a 6.0 theme can **not** be upgraded?

Comment: i guess not  because this tasks are for 6.2 and liferay 6.0 didnt had any bootstrap too, 

Plus this task has hardcodes values like 6.2.0
 patterns: [
     {
      match: /6\.2\.\d+\+/g,
      replacement: '7.0.0+'
     },
     {
      match: /6\.2\.0/g,
      replacement: '7.0.0'
     },
     {
      match: /6_2_0/g,
      replacement: '7_0_0'
     }
    ]
So, a manual task may need to be written.